# Rail Routes: Controller namespaces with constraints (subdomains)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3

The intention is to create a subdomain to hold all the administrative function (CRUD) and the name of the subdomain is "*admin*". The set of controllers responsible are also organized under the namespace of "*admin*", i.e. the controllers are under the *app/controllers/admin directory*.

Ideally, the following routes should be

```
admin.mydomain.com/products/     
admin.mydomain.com/products/new ...
```

and **not**

```
admin.mydomain.com/admin/products/
admin.mydomain.com/admin/products/new ...
```

I would like to keep the helpers with the "admin" prefix such as:

```
new_admin_product
edit_admin_product
```

---

My current routing code works and it is as below:

```
constraints :subdomain => "admin" do
  scope :module => "admin", :as => "admin" do
    resources :players
  end
end
```

Is this the right approach?

Comment: As I can see, this brakes all other routing for the resource `:players` if you use it again without the namespace. I'm looking for a workaround for this.

Comment: This is my mistake, I forgot the `:as => "admin"` which actually doesn't let overrides

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, this will give you precisely what you're after in the neatest fashion I know possible.