# From Namespace to Subdomain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, namespaces

what I want to do is to match the namespace route to subdomain route, for example in my routes.rb I have:

```
namespace :group do
  resources :groups
  resources :clubs
end
```

The current path of group index and each group is like:

```
lvh.me/group/groups
lvh.me/group/groups/1
```

But I don't like the URL here, I want to change the pages to:

```
group.lvh.me/groups
group.lvh.me/groups/1
```

As there will be several similar namespaces, is there a easier way for this?
Many thanks!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
constraints :subdomain => "admin" do
  scope :module => "admin", :as => "admin" do
    resources :players
  end
end
```

[Similar Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507484/rail-routes-controller-namespaces-with-constraints-subdomains)

Answer (score 0):

```
constraints :subdomain => "group" do
 scope :module => "group", :as => "group" do
  resources :group
 end
end
```