# make subdomain have a namespace as root?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, subdomain, router

Would it be possible to have a namespace to be the root for a subdomain in rails 3?

Currently my routes are:

```
  namespace :mobile do
    resources :home
    resources :profiles
    root :to => "/mobile/home#index"
  end

  constraints subdomain: 'm' do
    root :to => 'mobile/home#index'
    resources :home
    resources :profile
    resources :messages
    root :to => 'mobile/home#index'
  end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can but the namespace inside a subdomain constraint if that's what you're asking

```
constraints subdomain: 'm' do
  namespace :mobile do
    resources :home
    resources :profiles
  end
  resources :messages
  root :to => 'mobile/home#index'
end
```

Or there's this answer here: [From Namespace to Subdomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367636/from-namespace-to-subdomain) which advocates this approach:

```
constraints :subdomain => "mobile" do
  scope :module => "mobile", :as => "mobile" do
    resources :profiles
    resources :home
  end
end
```